# Change Virtualbox disk type from AHCI to RAID

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, bios, images

I made have an image that was made on a Dell computer. This Dell had "RAID mode" set in the bios. If I load and then boot the image on any other computer set to AHCI or AHCI/RAID, I get BSOD. Same happens in Virtualbox.

On a physical machine, I can just go to the bios and switch it. How can I do this in Virtualbox?

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same exact issue. Did you ever find a way to resolve it?

Comment: I think just changing a setting. I don't remember which one though. Found helpful info here: http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-motherboard

Answer (score 4):

Add the virtual disk to the Virtualbox VM as an IDE drive and set the IDE controller type to ICH6.

[image: Virtualbox IDE Controller type]

Comment: Didn't work, what does this actually (virtually) change when you select ICH6?

Comment: PIIX4 and ICH6 are different IDE drive controller chipset technologies. Please update your question with BIOS version and hard drive controller Make/Model of the RAID hardware controller on the physical computer. It may be that adding a SCSI controller to VB is the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the AHCI driver for the operating system before you switch it in the BIOS.  You can do this from Device Manager by updating the IDE bus device driver to the revelant AHCI bus driver for your computer.